# Why? full gc happen before twice minor gc?

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection

```
public class Test1 {

    public static final int _1MB = 1024 * 1024;

    public static void main(String agrs[]) {
            gc();
            System.out.println("hello world");
    }

    private static void gc() {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[3*_1MB];
            byte[] bytes1 = new byte[_1MB];
            bytes = null;
            byte[] bytes2 = new byte[18*_1MB];
    }
}
```

JDK1.8

```
-Xms25M -Xmx25M -XX:NewRatio=4 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

Output:

```
0.080: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 3677K->496K(4608K)] 3677K->3576K(26112K), 0.0031388 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
0.084: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1520K->0K(4608K)] 4600K->4416K(26112K), 0.0013931 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
0.085: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 0K->0K(4608K)] 4416K->4416K(26112K), 0.0009730 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
0.086: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 0K->0K(4608K)] [ParOldGen: 4416K->1298K(21504K)] 4416K->1298K(26112K), [Metaspace: 2635K->2635K(1056768K)], 0.0027873 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
hello world
```

Why Full GC before twice Minor GC?

Comment: where exactly? `PSYoungGen` is *before* `Full GC`

Comment: I think before Full GC there should have only one Minor GC ,but it came to two Minor GC .              byte[] bytes2 = new byte[18*_1MB]; the code of line generate one Minor GC ,then generate Full GC

Comment: so *you think* there should be only one minor GC before a Full GC? In such a case your thoughts are wrong, as simple as that

Answer (score 1):

The entire point of garbage collection is to do lots of minor collections and very little major collections. How is that happening is of course an implementation detail, but there are numerous posts here on stackoverflow that will shed some light.

What you see is absolutely normal and is just part of a healthy garbage collection process.